# how use own keyboard with uitextfields correctly

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

i want to use my own keyboard class with textfield. how can i use it simply and correctly?

now i've got something like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:overlay];


CGRect lRect = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 1, 1);
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(lRect, self.tc.frame)) {
    textFieldID = self.tc.tag;
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(lRect, self.tm.frame)) {
    textFieldID = self.tm.tag;
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(lRect, self.tp.frame)) {
    textFieldID = self.tp.tag;
}
string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"0"];
}
```

But my textfields are disabled and uiview places above textfields detect which textfield is selected.

```
-(UITextField *)initializeTextFieldWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andTag:(Byte)tag {
UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[tf setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:52.0/255.0 green:114.0/255.0 blue:151.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[tf setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[tf setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0]];
[tf setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[tf setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
[tf setDelegate:self];  
[tf setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
[tf setEnabled:NO];
[tf setTag: tag];
[tf setText:@"0.0"];
[self insertSubview:tf atIndex:0];

return tf;
}

-(void)write:(id)sender {
....
}
```

Comment: how can i do that i click in the uitextfield and my custom keyboard is shows on screen like original keyboard?

Comment: You can set the inputView of the text field to your custom view and it will automatically display your keyboard for you when it becomes the first responder.  Note that the line `[tf setEnabled:NO];` makes it so that it won't become active though....

Comment: @Inafziger - yes, but when i set my keyboard as inputView is in place as normal keyboard and keyboard view is extended to normal keyboard size. i want to set keyboard in center of screen. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is no method for using own keyboard as standard keyboard in other places on screen.